# Linking to other Excel workbooks and shortening paths

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I currently have lots of different excel workbooks in different folders on my computer, similar to financial workbooks for each month, and they're all in the same template. I'd like to make a "master" workbook which collates the info from each of these workbooks in a separate folder, for one large summary for each month together.

Now linking the different workbooks and a specific worksheet "Estimate" in them I can do fairly easily e.g. cell A1 might eventually look something like:

```
='C:\Finance\January\[Finance_Jan.xlsm]Estimate'!B10+'C:\Finance\February\[Finance_Feb.xlsm]Estimate'!B10+'C:\Finance\March\[Finance_March.xlsm]Estimate'!B10
```

The issue is, is that the formulae eventually get really long and if I want to add things or modify things it's quite difficult. Ideally, in the master workbook, I'd like to have a list of the Workbook names and their locations in a table. Then I could refer to them using their cells, so instead I could hopefully do something like, for example:

```
=D1!B10+D2!B10+D3!B10
```

with each location stored in D1, D2, etc.

However, trying something like this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function for that:

`=INDIRECT(D1&"!B10")+INDIRECT(D2&"!B10")+INDIRECT(D3&"!B10")`

If you don't have `'` around names you may need to use like

`INDIRECT("'" & D1 & "'!B10"...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've looked at the INDIRECT function and it does indeed seem to be what I need, but I can't get it to work with what you put. I keep getting the #REF! error. Possibly an issue with requiring quotation marks? At the moment I have for a test I have 2 workbooks, one at C:\Finance sheets\January\[Finance Jan.xlsm] and C:\Finance sheets\February\[Finance Feb.xlsm], with the master woorkbook at C:\Finance sheets\[Master sheet.xlsm]. I've tried playing around with the quotations but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see my edit.